# Use of MS SQL SERVER 2008 R2 EXPRESS with C# Windows Application?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-express

I've created a c# windows application(2.0 framework) which uses MS SQL database.
During developing I've used MS VISUAL STUDIO 2010 and SQL 2008 MANAGEMENT STUDIO.
My connection string during development is :

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=SL;Integrated Security=True");
```

Everything works fine....

Now I want to run this application on client system.
So installed MS SQL SERVER 2008 EXPRESS successfully on client system.
Stopped sql services of my system and copied the .mdf and .ldf files from my machine and pasted in "c:\Database\" of the client.
But while running comes the problem.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

The connection strings which I've tried many times are :

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\MSSQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SL;Integrated Security=True");

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\MSSQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SL;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=pass");

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\MSSQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename =C:\\Database\\SL.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
```

When I use `User ID=sa;Password=pass` in connection string I get:

> authentication failed for 'sa'

Am I missing some steps or doing wrong? Please tell me what should I do after copying the database from my system. What should be my connection string in C#?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You have only copied the files you need to attach the database into SQLExpress, take a look at using OSQL, or alternatively install the client tools onto the PC where you have SQLExpress and attach the databases.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, be sure to check out [Sres' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400683/use-of-ms-sql-sever-2008-r2-express-with-c-windows-application/7400717#7400717).
If you don't tell SQL Server in the connection string to attach your database (with `AttachDbFilename`, like in your third example), you have to do the attaching yourself as he said.

Concerning your three connection string examples: all of them only work under certain circumstances. You might want to check out [connectionstrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008).

Here are your three connection strings, plus short explanations of their issues:

`Data Source=.\MSSQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SL;Integrated Security=True`

--> This uses the current Windows user that you app is running under. So the current windows user must have permissions on the database on the client's machine.

`Data Source=.\MSSQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SL;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=pass`

--> This uses the special 'sa' user account. In order for this to work, you have to make sure that the following prerequisites are met:

- [Mixed mode authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143705%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) must be set up (if you don't do this, you only have Windows authentification, and 'sa' is a SQL Server authentification user name)
- the password of 'sa' needs to be specified, and of course it must be the same as on the development machine.

But this is not the best solution anyway. 'sa' is an admin account with full permissions, and you shouldn't use an admin account to access SQL Server with your app.
If you really want to use SQL Server authentification (instead of Windows authentification), it's better to create a new account with the minimal necessary permissions that your app needs.

`Data Source=.\MSSQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename =C:\Database\SL.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True`

--> same issue as with the first connection string (the current Windows user must have permissions).
Plus, `User Instance=True` needs to be enabled in SQL Server.
Quote from [connectionstrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008):

> To use the User Instance functionality you need to enable it on the
>   SQL Server. This is done by executing the following command:
>   sp_configure 'user instances enabled', '1'. To disable the
>   functionality execute sp_configure 'user instances enabled', '0'.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the new instance name is 'MSSQLEXPRESS'?

My R2 Express instance is called 'SQLEXPRESS' (this is actually due to a known bug in the [installer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958778)).

You might want to check that the instance is actually called what you think it is.

Comment: Yes when installation i've provided this name... ie MSSQLEXPRESS.